# Dates on x-axis, time series

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series, as.date

I have data covering a time period of over 25 years and I would like to see the years on the x-axis.

```
dates <- as.Date(Dollar[,1], "%d.%m.%Y") 
Dollar <- as.xts(Dollar[,2], dates)
plot(SWEDOLall, xaxt = "n", main="SMA", ann = FALSE)
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, at = labDates, format = "%y", labels = TRUE)
title(ylab = "Value")
title(xlab = "Time")
```

But my x-axis is just blank. Can anybody see what mistake I have made?

Comment: You need to add a reproducible example i.e. show some data (not all) that produce the blank x-axis that you talk about.

Comment: maybe your `at` values are not in the range of the plot

Comment: I think the values are disappearing because the dates variable is somehow being scaled wrong. In my answer below I cast it as a Posix date and just use the normal axis function instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to augment your example to get something to play with, but here is something that works. And I just changed it to eliminate lubridate...

```
library(xts)
d1 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),"years")
d2 <- rnorm(21,10,1)
Dollar <- data.frame(d1,d2)
dates <- as.Date(Dollar[,1], "%d.%m.%Y",tz="GMT") 
xtsplot <- as.xts(Dollar[,2], dates)
plot(xtsplot, xaxt = "n", main="SMA", ann = FALSE)
axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(dates),labels=format(dates,"%Y"))
title(ylab = "Value")
title(xlab = "Time")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! It worked! :) Instead of small single lines for each year (like your graphic has), there is just one big, black bar under my x-axis. Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: No, but in general if you need more control with your plots you are probably better off learning how to use ggplot2. It is a lot more flexible, but has a higher learning curve. You might want to post the new problem as a new post, but this time give it as a complete example so people can play with it. You will get answers much faster that way.